# Dirac delta function in the second derivative of $e^{-a|x|}$

Tags: absolute-value, dirac-delta

The function $e^{-a|x|}$ has a discontinuous first derivative at $x=0$, but seemingly a *continuous* second derivative there. Formally applying the product rule, we find that its second derivative is $a^2e^{-a|x|}$$-$but it turns out that the correct derivative is actually $a^2e^{-a|x|}-2a\delta(x)$.

- How can we obtain the Dirac delta term in the second derivative?
- What property of this function is causing the Dirac delta term to appear?

Comment: $e^{-a|x|} = e^{-ax}1_{x > 0} + e^{ax}1_{x < 0}$. The (distributional) derivative of $1_{x > 0}$ is $\delta(x)$, and for the multiplication of a distribution ($1_{x > 0} $) with a $C^\infty$ function ($e^{-ax}$) the product rule for the derivative works fine.

Comment: Thus $(e^{-ax}1_{x > 0})' = -a e^{-ax}1_{x > 0}+e^{-ax} \delta(x) = -a e^{-ax}1_{x > 0}+ \delta(x) $

Comment: "but seemingly a continuous second derivative there' ?? So we have a discontinuous function with a derivative? Please explain.

Comment: @Did: I simply mean that the graph of the second derivative seems continuous at $x=0$, nothing more.

Comment: ?? How do you "graph" the second derivative?

Comment: @Did: I used WolframAlpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2%2Fdx%5E2+e%5E%7B-%7Cx%7C%7D

Comment: In other words; highway to (mathematical) hell... Are you interested in understand mathematical objects or in punching formulas in WA?

Comment: And anyway, WA does not output a continuous function, does it?

Comment: @Did: Well, that's the reason I asked this question. Naively, I thought that it looked to be (and should be) continuous; it is not.

Comment: How you could come to imagine that the derivative of a discontinuous function could, first, exist and, even, be continuous, is the real mystery here... Do you have definitions of differentiability and continuity at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delta function comes due to the non-differentiability of the absolute value function at the point $0$. In that case, a delta function (centered at zero) gets added. Furthermore, the coefficient of the delta function is the "jump" of the function at the point i.e. the right limit minus the left limit at the point. In this case, it is $-2a$, hence we see that the factor $-2a\delta(x)$ gets added to the derivative.

More formally:

Given that the function is continuously differentiable except at a point $p$, then:
$$
Df(\phi) = f'(\phi) + J_f(p)* \delta_{p}(\phi)
$$

Where $\phi$ is a $C^\infty$ function with compact support, and $Df$ is the distributional derivative, and $f'$ is the classical derivative treated as a distribution, and $J_f(p)$ is the jump at $p$ which I described in the case earlier.

The proof of this is a little involved (rigorously, that is), but not difficult.

EDIT:

As Did pointed out, your logic prior to this is wrong, because if your function is not continuous, then it can't be differentiable. However, there is a concept of weak derivative, and I think you should read this up before you actually understand the terms of this answer (distributions, the topic is called). Furthermore, the delta function, well what is it? It's a a *distribution*, not a function, and when I answered this question I thought you had this background. Besides, do read up, because the subject is fascinating.

Comment: I am 6 years late to this but this is useful. My questions is, how do you know if I should be taking the discontinuity/jump as the difference between the right and left limit (instead of left and right)? In the case of left minus right, the sign would change and it'd be $+2a\delta(x)$ ?

Comment: @kowalski Hey, thanks for the question and sorry about the delayed response : I was asleep. As for the answer to your question : *directionally* speaking, an integral goes from left to right. If you remember how the Riemann integral of a function $f$ is defined, then you'll recall that you create a partition $[x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and then you take the "lower" sum $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i+1}-x_i)\inf_{x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}} f(x)$ (similarly the upper sum). In each of these sums, the quantity $x_{i+1}-x_i$ represents the "right-minus-left" nature of the integral. At the heart of it, however,...

Comment: ... you remember that the "integral" represents the "area" of a particular region below a graph. Of course, the area of a rectangle should match with its "usual" area. When you try to adapt the notion of the integral for just rectangles, it becomes clear that the area of a rectangle is positive, so the integral must be a "right-minus-left" because the real number line increases as one goes to the right, so "right-minus-left" always yields a positive value, which is what you expect an area to satisfy. That's basically the reason why "right-minus-left" is reflected in the integral and the jump.

Comment: Let me know, @kowalski if my explanation is not satisfactory. Also, I do not know why the number line increases as one goes to the right, but every theory of the integral (on the real line) will use this fact to ensure that signs match up for basic objects such as rectangle areas, which should be positive.